Reading dynamic sized byte arrays as integers
I have a binary file which has a header determining the length of each data element in the file. For example byte length of 2, 4 or 8 etc.
How to define to a function that's output can be a vector of i16, i32 or i64 for reading this data?
This would be something like this:
fn read_data<T: NoIdeaTrait>(&mut self, file: &mut File) -> Vec<T> {
        let mut data = Vec::new();
        let _ = file.read_to_end(&mut data);
        self.sampled_data = data
            // This is dynamic value
            .chunks(self.byte_per_block as usize)
            // Depending on the value this code would change
            // to take into account byte_per_block
            .map(|x| i32::from_le_bytes(x))
            .collect()
    }

What would be a sensible approach here?

I don't think from_le_bytes() is a member of any trait, maybe try make up your own trait.

from_le_bytes is a member of the FromBytes trait in the num_traits crate. It might be a good starting point.

Make up your own FromMyFile trait for it.
use std::io::{Cursor, Read};

trait FromMyFile<const SIZE: usize> {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: [u8; SIZE]) -> Self;
}

impl FromMyFile<4> for i32 {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: [u8; 4]) -> Self {
        i32::from_le_bytes(bytes)
    }
}
impl FromMyFile<8> for i64 {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: [u8; 8]) -> Self {
        i64::from_le_bytes(bytes)
    }
}

fn read_data<T: FromMyFile<SIZE>, const SIZE: usize>(mut bytes: impl Read) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut data = Vec::new();

    loop {
        let mut buf = [0; SIZE];
        match bytes.read(&mut buf) {
            Ok(s) if s == SIZE => {}
            Ok(0) => {
                break;
            }
            Ok(_) => {
                panic!("unexpected lenght")
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("io error {:?}", e);
                panic!()
            }
        }
        data.push(T::from_bytes(buf));
    }

    data
}

fn main() {
    let buffer = Cursor::new([0_u8; 256]);

    let vec: Vec<i32> = read_data(buffer.clone());
    println!("{:?}", vec);

    let vec: Vec<i64> = read_data(buffer);
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}

Edit
Maybe something like this?
// Result for reading my file
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyFileResult {
    I32(Vec<i32>),
    I64(Vec<i64>),
}

impl MyFileResult {
    pub fn from_read(mut bytes: impl Read) -> Self {
        let mut header = [0];
        bytes.read(&mut header).unwrap();
        match header[0] {
            0 => MyFileResult::I32(read_data(bytes)),
            1 => MyFileResult::I64(read_data(bytes)),
            _ => unreachable!("unknown encoding format"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // data with the first byte as the header determine the encoding size
    // - 0 for i32 encoded
    // - 1 for i64 encoded 
    let mut data = [0_u8; 257];
    {
        let data = data.clone();
        let buffer = Cursor::new(data);
        let res = MyFileResult::from_read(buffer);
        assert!(matches!(res, MyFileResult::I32(_)));
        println!("{:?}", res);
    }
    {
        // change the encoding style to i64 encoded
        data[0] = 1;
        let buffer = Cursor::new(data);
        let res = MyFileResult::from_read(buffer);
        assert!(matches!(res, MyFileResult::I64(_)));
        println!("{:?}", res);
    }
}


Would this work if I do not know the size at compile time? Eg. is it possible to read from a byte length of let's say 4 and then use read_data with that? So let byte_size = 4 and then use that somewhere? I could do a match for the length and then cast it, so yes, but I wonder if there'd be a better way using the type system.

I am not sure what you want, I assumed that any data type should be parse from a constant sized byte array, i.e. [u8;4]->i32, [u8;8]->i64. when you know your byte_size you should also know the data type.

Yes I do know it at that time. It is read from the header which is then passed to the read_data. What I probably meant was to wonder if it would have been possible to achieve this without resorting to matching types ie. with T: Traiting. I think this solution is fine by me. Thank you for your help!
